# Struggling with v5 to v4 pinescript Conversion, " The variable 'a' is declared in local scope, which may not be executed at every update." Error

Tags: pine-script

Struggling with v5 to v4 pinescript Conversion, The variable 'a' is declared in local scope, which may not be executed at every update. So, obtaining its historical values may lead to unexpected results. Error

```
if wm_pattern[1] and x == x[1] and a == a[1] and b == b[1] and c == c[1]
```

And I'm not really sure how to access the variable and modify inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error. It is a warning. It tells you that you are breaking the history of a series variable by assigning something to it in a local scope which may not be executed on each iteration.

You should define it in the global scope and update its value conditionally.

```
a = 0.0

if (your_condition)
    a := new_value
```

Comment: I want to change this indicator from version 4 to 5 this indicator
"Divergence for Many Indicators v4 by LonesomeTheBlue"

Comment: Just use the converter tool.